# Can have an Unicode ligature character more than one representation in UTF8? 

Tags: xml, unicode, utf-8

Can have an unicode ligature character `fi` (Unicode U+FB01) more than one representation in UTF8? Which one? For each normalization form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the meaning of “character,” which is rather obscure. In Unicode, “character” usually means a codepoint assigned to a character, and this does match exactly the intuitive concept of “character.”

A single codepoint, such as U+FB01, has only one representation in UTF-8, because UTF-8 defines an unambiguous algorithm for generating the encoded form.

An intuitive character, such as the fi ligature, may have different representations as a codepoint or as a sequence of codepoints, which each have UTF-8 representations. Unicode normalization rules define, in part, mappings between such alternatives.

But the compatibility mapping for U+FB01 (to U+0066 U+0069, i.e. “f” followed by “i”) does not preserve the identity of an intuitive character: the ligature is mapped to two normal letters.

On the other hand, you can ask for, or suggest, ligature behavior by inserting U+200D ZERO WIDTH JOINER (ZWJ) between two letters, like “f” and “i”. In a sense, the sequence U+0066 U+200D U+0069 is an alternative representation of the fi ligature, but this is not a formal property of character, and it depends on rendering software whether it pays attention to ZWJ.

Comment: I wonder why the OP is dealing with the Latin ligature compatibility code points? Those are there for roundtripping with legacy encodings. The right way to handle ligatures is to let the font make the decisions, possibly selecting the standard and/or optional ones that the font provides. You *should* never have to encode them yourself. That said, there’ve been times I’ve had to do so — under protest.

Answer (score 3):

The character should [be encoded as](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fb01/index.htm) `0xEF 0xAC 0x81` in `utf-8` but the same character can be decomposed to an `f` and an `i` in sequence, which together are `0x66 0x69`. Your question is actually answered directly by [this chart from the unicode specification](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms):

[image: normalized forms of ligatures]

As you can see, the `NFD` and `NFC` normalizations are still using the same codepoint for the ligature while the `NFKD` and `NFKC` forms use the `f` + `i` combination.